# ImportError: cannot import name 'while_v2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling

I have installed 'tensortrade' successfully. But when I import tensortrade I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'while_v2'
```

python: 3.6.5

tensorflow : '1.10.0'

keras : '2.2.4'

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there might be some incompatibilities between libraries. What I will suggest is to create a **virtual environment** and to reinstall all those libraries in there, because I also had a lot of errors when I tried to install new libraries without a virtual environment.

```
virtualenv -p python3.6.5 .venv_my_venv_name
```

Also, this might not be the case, but I also had some issues between keras and tensorflow, I will suggest to intall this versions:

```
tensorflow==1.14.0
keras==2.3.0
```

Hope it helps!